# React loading screen using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building an app in React where I fetch playlist data in an onClick event handler. Because fetching data takes some time I want to show a loading screen. Currently I'm initialising the loading state as true and make it false fetching is done. However, because the code within the promise is ran asynchronously, the loading state is changed to false before fetching data is done. I believe I can use useEffect for this but I'm not sure how. I've been looking for an example but couldn't find one, so I came here.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const history = useHistory()

const fetchPlaylist = (playlistId) => {  
    setIsLoading(true)
    fetch('/spotify/get-tracks-data', {headers: {
        'id': playlistId
    }})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      history.push({pathname: `playlists/${playlistId}`, data})
      setIsLoading(false)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Where is `fetchPlaylist ` called? Where do you update loading state to `false` before the Promise chain completes? What are you trying to do with the route transition? This likely unmounts the component this code snippet is running in and you'll likely see errors related to "...updating state of unmounted...".

Comment: fetchPlaylist is called in a different component as onClick={() => fetchPlaylist(id)}. I update loading state to false before this code snippet within a useEffect hook where I initialise other states, such as userData. I call history.push to route the user to a new screen while passing the fetched data along. Then in the new screen, the data is used in another component.

Comment: `useEffect` callback and this `fetchPlaylist` callback don't run at the same time. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all components involved?

Comment: I believe the `setIsLoading(false)` is not useful here since you redirect to another page. If you want to make any loading transition between two page, you want to build a global loader. Your current loading is in a local state, so it could just be used as a fetching loader only, and `useEffect` works for this case before it redirects to a new page. Once it redirects, the loader will be immediately `cut off` or `fade out` depending on your implementation.

Comment: @DrewReese Here you can find the code example of the involved components: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-mendel-cs5eu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. I left out some stuff that is not related to the issue. Also, instead of fetching I'm just setting the states with mock data for this example.

Comment: I don't understand your codesandbox? What are we to look for in it? It doesn't appear to be an accurate representation of the above code snippet.

Comment: @DrewReese it shows the other hooks that are changing the loading state. The main problem, as described in this question, is that I want to change the loading state to false after fetch(...).then(history.push()), so I can show a loading screen while the next page is being loaded.

Comment: But the sandbox you linked doesn't do that, it just enqueues two `setIsLoading` updates in the callback, the second overwrites the first and nothing is actually updated (the effect) because the end state is the same as the starting state.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you are trying to do now. You want a loading indicator to render ***during*** the route transition. For this you would need to lift the loading state to at least the router level so it can render a loading indicator over any routes being rendered and/or transitioned to/from. From a route's perspective it is either matched and rendered, or it isn't. It will unmount as soon as the route PUSH is processed.

Comment: @DrewReese So how would I do that? I couldn't find an example...

Comment: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) covers the general pattern. You can define the state in the component rendering the router and pass props down, use the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or move into a global app state management library like [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, like Drew suggested, I [lifted the loading state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) and wrapped the Router component in a higher-order component called 'Loading' like so:

```
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router
  } from "react-router-dom";
import App from '../App';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Loading = () => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const showLoading = () => (
        setLoading(true)
    )

    const hideLoading = () => (
        setLoading(false)
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(loading)
    }, [loading])

    return(
        <Router>
            <App loading={loading} showLoading={() => showLoading()} hideLoading={() => hideLoading()}/>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Loading
```

And then my fetchPlaylist function in the App component changed like this:

```
const fetchPlaylist = (playlistId) => {  
showLoading()
fetch('/spotify/get-tracks-data', {headers: {
    'id': playlistId
}})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  history.push({pathname: `playlists/${playlistId}`, data})
  hideLoading()
})
```

I'm quite confident that this is not the cleanest way but it works...